# How the mobile app version information are maintained in PhoneGap build?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, version, phonegap

I am new to PhoneGap builds. I want to know how to maintain the versions of App that are frequently published in Apple Store and Google Play Store.

If the next version is published, will the users of previous versions be asked to upgrade to the latest version without any code for upgrade except the version detail.

Where to indicate app version information in PhoneGap builds?

If suppose one version is published without the version information, will the users ask to upgrade for later versions?

Please let me know the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the phonegap version will not mean anything for application users, it only helps the developer (of course if the developer wants it).

The update will take care of the google play or the apple store if you've changed something in the app and want to set up a new version on the Store.

Please check this [link](https://blog.phonegap.com/phonegap-7-0-1-now-on-build-and-it-includes-some-important-changes-89087fe465f5).

Comment: proofzy, I didn't ask about the versions of the PhoneGap that is used by developers.  Currently I don't have an issue with that. I am using PhoneGap (v0.4.5). I want to know how the users my app shall be informed about the release of my next version. Am I need to do in the current version accessed by users? If I haven't indicated the version number in the released build, how the next release will be informed to the users?

Comment: @vsanandan You can simple use push notifications or just upload new version on google play and user will be notified by store...

Comment: Thanks proofzy. I need to publish the next version of the app and test by accessing the app of previous version.